# Error 429. Active X component can't create object

Tags: vba, ms-word, com, activex

So, I have registered a dll as COM component to be used in a VBA project. Problem is when I run the project i keep getting this error

> Error 429. Active X component can't create object

at the following line of code:

```
Dim myObject
Set myObject = New AttachIt.AttachIt1
```

I checked and I don't miss any references or at least this is what I think. Here are the references :

[Click to view references](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBNeA.jpg)

What is funny is that I isolate that instance in another project like this and works fine:

```
Public Sub Special_Initialization()

    'AttachIt.AttachIt1 xxx = New AttachIt.AttachIt1
    MsgBox "aaa"
    Dim myObject
    Set myObject = New AttachIt.AttachIt
    MsgBox "bbbb"

End Sub
```

Some work around that I found is if I move Attachit as last priority reference will work.

Also if I add some random reference I will not get that error. If I uncheck it will also work. Is so weird because I cannot find any logic on whats happening.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Could be the extra digit in the first code example, typo causing this?