# Object can't be created for ActiveX component

Tags: excel, vba, activex, vba7, brother-bpac

I created a excel macro tool, that will be able to make data matrix labels by asking the user each parameter, and then once the entire string for the label is made it gets sent to a brother PT9800PCN printer. After pawing through the many issues I had I was finally able to get it working. However, I need to deploy it to a different computer. Through transferring all the files, and drivers needed to print the labels, it seems that I can't get the macro to work with the printer.

Each time I go through the process of gathering all the data from the user, I then continue to get this error which won't allow me to normally send to the printer. Excel vb continues to highlight my line: `Set ObjDoc = CreateObject("bpac.Document")` . Stating the issue is a run-time error 429.  I checked to make sure that I pulled all of the necessary references and libraries that I had on my original machine, as well as ensuring that I have the necessary drivers for my Brother Printer. On the computer that must house this macro I've even uninstalled and re-installed the P-touch software, and drivers for the printer. This goes for the reference libraries as well. Yet I'm still struggling to find the proper solution.

[image]

I've looked online for Microsoft's official description of the run-time error, as well as running and reviewing the reference libraries that I had set on the original laptop. I've also looked here on StackOverflow for a similar issue that might assist me. Specifically this post here: *[Error 429. Active X component can't create object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51761020/error-429-active-x-component-cant-create-object)*. Unfortunately I still haven't found what may be causing the issue. Hoping maybe by posting my issue there can maybe some hope in resolving it.

```vb
Public Sub CreateAndPrintLabel()
    Dim CreateLabel As VbMsgBoxResult
    Dim labelInfo As String
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim ObjDoc As Object

    ' Step 1: Ask the user if they wish to create a label
    CreateLabel = MsgBox("Do you wish to create a label?", vbYesNo)

    If CreateLabel = vbYes Then
    
        ' Step 2: Prompt for each parameter
        Dim licensePlate As String
        Dim partNumber As String
        Dim Description As String
        Dim expirationDate As String
        
        Dim validInput As Boolean
        Dim userInput As String
        
        ' Step 2a: Enter SupplierPlateID with exit option
        'Do
            'userInput = InputBox("Enter SupplierPlateID" & vbNewLine & _
                                 "Press 'Cancel' to terminate the process.")
            'If userInput = "" Then Exit Sub
            'licensePlate = userInput
            licensePlate = InputBox("Enter License Plate:")
            'validInput = ValidateSupplierPlateID(licensePlate)
            'If Not validInput Then
             '   MsgBox "Invalid SupplierPlateID."
            'End If
        'Loop While Not validInput

        ' Step 2b: Enter Part Number with exit option
        Do
            userInput = InputBox("Enter Part Number (must have two '-' and end with '-875')" & vbNewLine & _
                                 "Press 'Cancel' to terminate the process.")
            If userInput = "" Then Exit Sub
            partNumber = userInput
            validInput = ValidatePartNumber(partNumber)
            If Not validInput Then
                MsgBox "Invalid Part Number. It must have two '-' and end with '-875'."
            End If
        Loop While Not validInput

        Description = InputBox("Enter Description:")

        ' Step 2c: Enter Expiration Date with exit option
       expirationDate = InputBox("Enter Experation Date (YYYY-MM-DD)" & vbNewLine & _
                                "Press 'Cancel' to terminate the process.")

        ' Step 3: Validate and display entered information
        labelInfo = licensePlate & " | " & partNumber & " | " & Description & " | " & expirationDate
        confirmMsg = "Is the following information correct?" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & labelInfo
        confirmed = MsgBox(confirmMsg, vbYesNo) = vbYes
        
        
        'Update the label's caption with the user-created string in the Userform
        UserForm1.Label3.Caption = labelInfo
        

        ' Step 4: Allow correction or confirmation
        If Not confirmed Then
            ' Provide an option to go through the steps again if the information was incorrect
            Call CreateAndPrintLabel
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        ' Store labelInfo in cell B12 on Sheet1
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B12").Value = labelInfo
        
        
        
         ' Step 5: Confirm if user wants to print
            printLabel = MsgBox("Do you wish to print the label?", vbYesNo)
    
                If printLabel = vbNo Then
                    Exit Sub ' Exit the macro if user selects "No" for printing
                End If
            
            ' Step 5.5: Print the label using Brother printer
            Set ObjDoc = CreateObject("bpac.Document")
            sPath = "C:\Users\giovanni.fontanetta\Documents\My Labels\Matrix.lbx"
            
            
            
            ' Open lbx file
            If ObjDoc.Open(sPath) Then
                ' Set text for the entire label
                ObjDoc.SetText 0, dataMatrixContent
                
                ObjDoc.GetObject("dataMatrix").text = labelInfo
                
                ' Print the label
                ObjDoc.StartPrint "", bpoDefault
                ObjDoc.PrintOut 1, bpoDefault
                ObjDoc.EndPrint
                
                ' Close lbx file
                ObjDoc.Close
            Else
                MsgBox "Failed to open label file."
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "ActiveX Data Matrix control not found on the sheet."
        End If
    'End If
End Sub
Function ValidatePartNumber(partNumber As String) As Boolean
    If CountCharacter(partNumber, "-") = 2 And Right(partNumber, 4) = "-875" Then
        ValidatePartNumber = True
    Else
        ValidatePartNumber = False
    End If
End Function

Function CountCharacter(ByVal text As String, ByVal character As String) As Long
    CountCharacter = (Len(text) - Len(Replace(text, character, ""))) / Len(character)
End Function

Function IsValidExpirationDate(expirationDate As String) As Boolean
    Dim regex As Object
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    regex.Pattern = "^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$"
    
    If regex.Test(expirationDate) Then
        Dim currentDate As Date
        currentDate = Date
        Dim futureDate As Date
        futureDate = DateAdd("yyyy", 6, currentDate)
        
        If DateValue(expirationDate) <= futureDate Then
            IsValidExpirationDate = True
        End If
    End If
End Function

Function ValidateSupplierPlateID(supplierPlateID As String) As Boolean
    If Len(supplierPlateID) = 8 And Left(supplierPlateID, 2) = "PC" Then
        ValidateSupplierPlateID = True
    Else
        ValidateSupplierPlateID = False
    End If
End Function

Sub Print_Label()
    Dim bRet As Boolean
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim ObjDoc As bpac.Document
    Set ObjDoc = CreateObject("bpac.Document")
    sPath = "C:\Users\giovanni.fontanetta\Documents\My Labels\Matrix.lbx"
    
    'Open lbx file
    bRet = ObjDoc.Open(sPath)
    If (bRet <> False) Then

        ' Start Print-Setting
        ObjDoc.StartPrint "", bpoDefault

        ' Ask the user how many copies to print
        Dim numCopies As Integer
        numCopies = InputBox("Enter the number of copies to print:", "Number of Copies", 1)

        For i = 1 To numCopies
            ObjDoc.PrintOut 1, bpoDefault
        Next i

        ' Finish Print-Setting and start the printing
        ObjDoc.EndPrint

        ' Close lbx file
        ObjDoc.Close
    End If
End Sub
```